# Requirement of telemetry and application usage in ASP.NET MVC.Looking for third party tools if any?

Tags: web-apps

We have a ASP.net MVC web site which we have developed for one of our customers. There is a new requirement now to introduce telemetry in the application with .we are currently looking to buy licenses off the shelf product for this requirement instead of implementing something from scratch.We are open to extend the OOB feature if at all possible to meet our extended requirements using active directory.i have also listed down most of the requirements we have.Any suggestions would be really help full.

Primary Need - general report (xls or tabular online report) that includes:

· Alias (email alias of the windows authenticated user, this site is intranet facing and supports only windows authentication).

· GAL title (title retrieved from the exchange server, may require some customization i believe)

· Sub-Region, Region, Subsidiary, Area(based on the geographic location.)

· Time/date stamp of access

· TAB of access

· Nice to have: new date/time stamp for each click of "go"(click on few searches we have in the application ) and possibly "export"(think of it as just another controller) · Integrating some custom application information (like users role and title available in the application database )on the reports.

Nice to have:

· Did they click on hyperlinked information (call to a specific webpage)

· How long they spend on the site(total time spent per session)

· Click paths(Pages viewed during that session)

· Active Time / Engagement Time (Average amount of time visitors spend actually interacting with content on a web page, based on mouse moves, clicks, hovers and scrolls. NOT just Session Duration and Page View Duration / Time on Page) Some items we will be reporting on from the Primary report need: · Which pages hit more often than rest · Breakdown of titles, geos accessing.